# Go: Varint returns different values than read

Tags: encoding, go

Why does binary.Varint return different results than binary.Read?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    b := []byte{0x18, 0x2d, 0x44, 0x54, 0xfb, 0x21, 0x09, 0x40}
    var i1 int64

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b)
    binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &i1)
    fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", i1, i1)

    i2, _ := binary.Varint(b)
    fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", i2, i2)
}
```

Returns:

> %!s(int64=4614256656552045848), 4614256656552045848
>   %!s(int64=12), 12

Here's a link to the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vlrl_CHq0v

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `%T` instead of `%s` in your `fmt.Printf`s. That's why you're getting the `%!s(...)` instead of `int64` like you'd get with `%T`.

Comment: It's not about the string formatting but about the fact, that they have different return values: 12 and 4614256656552045848

Comment: Yes, true. I was just pointed that out for yours and others benefit (I saw the error and did the research to find the right formatting string and figured I would share) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Varint](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?csw=1#varints) is a specific encoding, that means that the byte value it reads off the wire/from the file is not an actually integer value, but an encoding. Read on the other hand, just reads bytes in whichever byte order you passed to it.